# How to convert a 3d model into an array of points

Tags: python, arrays, 3d

I'm building my own 3d engine, I need to import 3d models into it, but I don't know how to do it.
I wonder if it is possible to convert a 3d model into an array of points; if it is possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3d models come in file formats such as .obj, .stl, .fbx and many many more. These files, which represent the 3d model, are usually lists of vertices themselves (or other data about the model, such as normals or texture coordinates). You can find the formats of these files online and in your engine, read from the file just as you would any other file and put the data you want into arrays.

I would recommend starting by downloading some 3d model in a .obj format and then opening it in a text editor. Look at what is inside and think about you can read the information you want from it. You can also find more about the .obj file format [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't something I've done before; but the premise is interesting so I thought I'd share my idea as I have worked with grids (pretty much an array) in 3D space during my time at university.

If you consider 3D space, you could represent that space as a three dimensional array quite simply with each dimension representing an axis. You could then treat each element in that array as a point in space and populate that with a value (say a Boolean of true/false, 1/0) to identify the points of your model within that three dimensional space.

All you'd need is the Height, Width and Depth of your model, with each one of these being the dimensions in your array. Populate the values with 0/false if the model does not have a point in that space, or 1/true if it does. This would then give you a representation of your model as a 3D array.

Comment: Thank you very much for the help